# Can the expression « ne pas payer de mine » mean "one is not a looker"?

Tags: expressions

> Cette vieille musicienne, elle **payait pas d’mine**, mais elle jouait vraiment bien !

I wonder if the expression « ne pas payer de mine » can only refer to one's deceptive appearance hiding one's true talent or character. Or can it also mean "one is not good-looking physically"?

---

I usually associate this locution with this meaning:

> Her appearance belies her true talent as a musician.

But can it ever have an alternative meaning of:

> She doesn't exactly shine in the physical attraction department, but her musical talent more than makes up for it.

Comment: I don't really see any difference between your two ideas. But I can say that you can use it even without stating something positive behind. *"Cet appartement ne paye pas de mine"* means that apartment doesn't look good. Nothing good hidden behind that.

Comment: Simon Déchamps, I disagree. "Ne paye pas de mine" refers to something that doesn't look good or doesn't give a good first impression but finally appears to be way better that we thought.

Maybe it has a slightly different meaning between two different french-speaking countries, but that is how I use it.

Comment: +1 with Orgoss here

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my experience, *ne pas payer de mine* is used either when you **know** that the inner quality of something is better than it looks,

> Cette petite brasserie ne paye pas de mine, mais on y mange très bien.

or when you're put off by its aspect and **waiting to see** if it's better than it looks.

> Ce magasin ne paye pas de mine ! *[mais j'attends d'être dedans pour voir]*

The expression is mostly used to describe things, and when applied to people, it is always neutral or practical/professional-oriented. I've never heard it used to describe someone's lack of physical attractiveness or sex appeal.